# processes =false in local distribution in dask

Tags: macos, python-2.7, dask, dask-distributed

I read the documentation of DASK . It is written there in local distributed form that 
client = Client(processes=False)

I would like to know why is the processes mentioned as false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this means that any `dask` code will run multi threaded and not with multiprocessing.

It is not recommended to use multithreading for cpu intensive tasks in python because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). however if the majority of your work is IO related then multithreading is a good option, because you can have much more threads then processes.